# How to find longest increasing subsequence among all simple paths of an unweighted general graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, lis

Let **G = (V, E)** be an unweighted general graph in which every vertex **v** has a weight **w(v)**.

An increasing subsequence of a simple path **p** in **G** is a sequence of vertices of **p** in which the weights of all vertices along this sequence increase. The simple paths can be closed paths.

A longest increasing subsequence (LIS) of a simple path **p** is an increasing subsequence of **p** such that has maximum number of vertices.

The question is that, how to find a longest increasing subsequence among all simple paths of **G**?

Note that the graph is undirected, therefore it is not a directed acyclic graph (DAG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very fast algorithm for solving this problem. The longest increasing subsequence in the graph is a subsequence of a path in the graph, and each path must belong purely to a single connected component. So if we can solve this problem on connected components, we can solve it for the overall graph by finding the best solution across all connected components.

Next, think about the case where you're solving this problem for a connected graph G. In that case, the longest increasing subsequence you could find would be formed by sorting the nodes by their weight, then traversing from the lowest-weight node to the second, then to the third, then to the fourth, etc. If there are any ties or duplicates, you can just skip them. In other words, you can solve this problem by

1. Sorting all the nodes by weight,
2. Discarding all but one node of each weight, and
3. Forming an LIS by visiting each node in sequence.

This leads to a very fast algorithm for the overall problem. In time O(m + n), find all connected components. For each connected component, use the preceding algorithm in time O(Sort(n)), where Sort(n) is the time required to sort n elements (which could be Θ(n log n) if you use heapsort, Θ(n + U) for bucket sort, Θ(n lg U) for radix sort, etc.). Then, return the longest sequence you find.

Overall, the runtime is O(m + n + &Sort(n)), which beats my previous approach and should be a lot easier to code up.

---

I had originally posted this answer, which I'll leave up because I think it's interesting:

Imagine that you pick a simple path out of the graph G and look at the longest increasing subsequence of that path. Although the path walks all over the graph and might have lots of intermediary nodes, the longest increasing subsequence of that path really only cares about

- the first node on the path that's also a part of the LIS, and
- from that point, the next-largest value in the path.

As a result, we can think about forming an LIS like this. Start at any node in the graph. Now, travel to any node in the graph that (1) has a higher value than the current node and (2) is reachable from the current node, then repeat this process as many times as desired. The goal is to do so in a way that gives the longest possible sequence of increasing values.

We can model this process as finding a longest path in a DAG. Each node in the DAG represents a node in the original graph G, and there's an edge from a node u to a node v if

- there's a path from u to v in G, and
- w(u) < w(v).

This is a DAG because of that second condition, even though the original graph isn't a DAG.

So we can solve this overall problem in a two-step process. First, build the DAG described above. To do so:

1. Find the connected components of the original graph G and label each node with its connected component number. Time: O(m + n).
2. For each node u in G, construct a corresponding node u' in a new DAG D. Time: O(n).
3. For each node u in G, and for each node v in G that's in the same SCC as u, if w(u) < w(v), add an edge from u' to v'. Time: Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case, Θ(n) in the best case.
4. Find the longest path in D. This path corresponds to the longest increasing subsequence of any simple path in G. Time: O(m + n).

Overall runtime: Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case, Θ(m + n) in the best-case.